# "Invalid spriteFrame for sprite" when initializing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I'm quite new to obj-c and I've been stuck on this one for a few hours now..

I am getting the error

```
Invalid spriteFrame for sprite
```

when trying to add a sprite to a child.

Here's my code.

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB {
    NSLog(@"Initialized");
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Artwork.plist"];
}

-(void)openAbout {
    _aboutSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"About-1.png"];
    _aboutSprite.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    _aboutSprite.position = ccp(0, 0);
    [self addChild:_aboutSprite];
}
```

Not sure what is wrong here.. I've looked at a few code samples and they are pretty much identical to mine. I am using SpriteBuilder.

Comment: Are you sure the `About-1.png` exists and is added to the bundle? Can you add the whole cocos2d exception for the `Invalid spriteFrame for sprite` error?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
_aboutSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"About-1.png"];
```

`spriteWithSpriteFrameName` is the method that looks up for sprite frames loaded by `CCSpriteFrameCache`.

You are using `spriteWithImageNamed`, which looks for an actual image file called "About-1.png", however such image clearly doesn't exist - "About-1.png" is the frame name.

Comment: Please explain your answer in brief to make it more useful for OP and other readers.

Comment: @MohitJain: There's really not much to explain, he just used the wrong method. I added some details though.

Comment: @JustKidding Apparently that doesn't exist anymore. No known class method for selector spriteWithSpriteFrameName.

Comment: `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` is no longer publicly available in cocos2d v3